# Data transfer from one pc to another using pulse coded modulation

Tags: c++

i have an question for you,that can we transfer data from one pc to another using PCM(Pulse Coded Modulation)technique(With cpp's socket programming)?If yes then how?

Comment: This is intriguing. Can you elaborate? PCM is usually used to represent analog data with digital outputs, what sort of data are you interested in sending and why does it need to be PCM?

Comment: yeh ,actually i want to transfer an digital data using this technique over one computer to another.So i don't know exactly how to perform it,but i heard that its possible with cpp..

Comment: PCM is signalling method. Are you trying to write a device driver for this PCM modulator? Or are you trying to write a utility to talk to the device driver of this PCM modulator?

Comment: and why pcm is..coz its given in our syllabus.

Comment: i am trying to send digital data over it.

Comment: Yes we know you are trying to send digital data over analog signal. Are you trying to write a code that will convert this digital signal to analog signal (device driver), or are you trying to talk to the device driver to send your digital information (userspace utility). These are 2 different things. In either case yes it is possible.

Comment: trying to perform both of above

Comment: ll u plz elaborate any one of above

Comment: You need to have a hardware that will convert the signal (a PCM modulator/demodulator). The only piece of hardware PCM in a computer is the sound card. This is probably not what you have in mind. If you have a PCM modulator/demodulator that connects to RS232C, all you need to learn is what codes will this PCM accept. This is like going back to the 80's dialup where you send sequences to the serial port and let the PCM modulator/demodulator do the work. You will then need to tell the modulator to switch to data transfer mode. In summary your code will be talking to an RS232C.

Comment: However, you can write a device driver to create a socket like port and allow socket programs to connect to it. This socket driver will be the one sending the command sequences to S232C and telling the PCM modulator/demodulator what to do.

Comment: I think you are re-inventing dialup. Here's an example of a PCM that sends data over analog line. http://www.google.com/patents/US6522688

Comment: so what should i have to refer for write a device driver to create a socket

Comment: Here's some more information regarding difference between encoding and modulation http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-encoding-and-vs-modulation/

Comment: hey thanks once again..hnd

Comment: After reading your conversation with @Ozraptor it seems you are just interested in socket programming to send PCM data. The manpage of getaddrinfo has sample socket programming. Here's a link http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot transfer data from one PC to another "using" PCM per se. However, you can certainly transfer PCM encoded data using C++ and socket programming, which is actually using TCP/IP or UDP/IP etc to transfer your data between PCs.

You would do this by establishing a socket connection between your sending/receiving machines, and then streaming your PCM encoded data into the socket interface on the sending side, and reading it back out at the receiver side.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the code for your syllabus at [clickNcode](http://clickncode.pythonanywhere.com)

Please mark it as correct if you find it useful.